# Duda con Nodejs como llamar mi action del html

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs

me explico , a lo que quiero referirme es que en mi archivo app.js tengo lo siguiente **/Register**

```
app.post('/Register',function(req,res){
    let body = req.body;
    let { EmailR, PasswordR} = body;
    let data = new User({
        EmailR,
        PasswordR: bcrypt.hashSync(PasswordR,15),
    })
    data.save((err,doc) => {
        if (err){
            res.send('DATA NOT SEND ')
        }else{
            if (doc){
                res.send('Data received:');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

en mi formulario tengo algo como esto

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:27017/Register" method="post" id="Form2" autocomplete="off">


</form>
```

si yo le quito el https://127.0.0.1:27017 y solo dejo el /Register , me da error 404 not found. eso quiere decir que no encuentra la ruta pero de que manera puedo poner la ruta para que funcione

**ACTUALIZADO**

Asi tengo la connexion a la base de datos

```
  const uri = "mongodb+srv://JohnTest:9hzkVsDSTyxiHYJ@cluster0-eoq97.mongodb.net/Register?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology:true ,native_parser:true });
    client.connect(function (err,same)  {
        if (same){
            console.log('connect to db')

        }else{
            if (err){
                console.log('not connect');
            }
        }
    });
```

```
app.listen( PR = config.app.port,  (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('>>> Listen on PORT: ' + PR);
});
```

Comment: Veo que usas el puerto TCP 27017, el cual es el puerto predeterminado del servidor MongoDB. ¿Has cambiado el puerto de Mongo? ¿Tu aplicación *Express* escucha en el puerto 27017? ¿Podrías aclarar cómo levantas tu servidor NodeJS? Saludos

Comment: estoy usando MongoClient , tambien probe con mongoose, pero en esta quise probar el cambio de puertos usando MongoClient, y me sale este error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` lo puse en el puerto 3000,

Comment: ¿Cual es la ruta del formulario al momento de realizar el registro?

Comment: Creo que tienes un conflicto de conceptos. Una solicitud a una ruta relativa (sin escribir el *host*) el navegador la interpretará como una solicitud al puerto `http` 80, por defecto del `host` al que pertenece la página o documento actualmente cargada en la vista. Si tu servidor (no hablo de Node, sino de Apache o ngnix o ISS, o el que uses como servidor web) no tiene habilitada o configurada una ruta en `/Register`, te devolverá siempre un error 404. Me parece que lo que debes hacer es analizar y separar la lógica del servidor web de la lógica de tu API en NodeJS.

Comment: al presionar el submit Ella queda **http://127.0.0.1:3000/Register**

Comment: De hecho, lo usual para este tipo de configuraciones es usar un servidor proxy, que se encargue del redireccionamiento de paquetes en las solicitudes a la API, y no exponer directamente el puerto TCP de tu aplicación de Node directamente a la red. Puedes configurar que todas las peticiones a `tu_host/api` sean redireccionadas internamente a `localhost:<tu_puerto>`. Así el atributo action de tu formulario puedes escribirlo como `action="/api/Register"`. La pregunta es, ¿usas un servidor web?

Comment: ok si con servidor web , te refieres a el Xaamp eso no lo he activado porque desde el mismo intellij IDEA me despliega un localhost